# segfault when assigning token(strtok) to node

Tags: c

Getting a segmentation error on the following segment of code that is expected to take a variable line of input ex(line1 = JMP START  line2 = START LOAD R1 A1).

```
while(fgets(inputt,249,stdin) != NULL){
    if (count==0){
        if(inputt[0] != ' '){
            token = strtok(inputt," ");
            //v segfault
            datanode->name=token;
        }

        token = strtok(inputt," ");
        if(token != NULL){
            //vsegfault
            datanode->action=token;
            }

        token = strtok(inputt," ");
        if(token != NULL){
            //v segfault
            datanode->datta=token;
            }
        token = strtok(inputt," ");
        if(token != NULL){
 //v segfault
            datanode->datta2=token;
            }

        list = createList(datanode);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: That looks as if `datanode` is `NULL` or uninitialised.

Comment: Also note that `strtok` takes the string to tokenise on the first call, and `NULL` on subsequent calls. As is, you are extracting the first word of the line repeatedly.

Comment: You probably need to make a copy of the token, e.g. with `strdup`, before assigning it to the structure. This question really needs a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is `count`? Also, I don't think you quite understand how `strtok` works. You start with `if(inputt[0] != ' ')` but that is what `strtok` does for you. [Please RTM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb.aspx)